# Getting file from sd card to read

Tags: java, android, file-io

just got a little hiccup in getting the file I/O where,a file in the sd is stored under the user given file name.
the file name is got through use of intent. Have poked around to see some solution but something seems to be missed out.

The task is, need to get to the path of the given file name where the content of the file is to be read.
in the given textview.The file name is got through intent but still the File.io Doesnt seem to get the file to read gives a file not found catch throw exception

have mentioned the required read & write permissions in the manifest files already.

any help with a brief example would be great. Thanks

```
    public class EmailRead extends Activity {
TextView EtV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.email_read);

    EtV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Email_Txt);

    Intent inn = getIntent();
    String Fname = inn.getStringExtra("FileName");

    File SdC = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File file =new File(SdC,SdC.getPath() + "/myDirTab" + "/" + Fname + ".txt");

    if (file.exists()) {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            Log.e("This is for inside", "The Bufferreader");
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append("/n");

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            Log.e("Error in reading line ", "In the catch part of read");
        }

            EtV.setText(text);
    } else {

        Log.e("This is for file Exception", "File not found");
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Any hint as of what's messing up or a hint for a work around would be good

Answer (score 1):

In wich part crash,when creating file or in the buffered reader??

Comment: THE ERROR is the part where the file is not found, whereas on manually searching for the file through ddms provides the file with some notable change in the file size.So the file is written but not found

Comment: in the file.exists()??EDIT:Ok I see.Are you sure that the file is located there??